# "Cannot open output file. Permission denied" error while debugging C++ codes in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, permission-denied

I'm getting the following error when I try to debug my code in Eclipse:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Pointers.exe: Permission denied
```

I'm using Windows 10, have McAfee antivirus, have turned the firewall and live-scan off, but I am still getting this error. I have my **Path** environment variable set to the bin folder of MinGW. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sound *a lot* like an AV-related problem. Or maybe you should check if you could write to the output folder.

Comment: @Emma 's link probably has it. Make absolutely certain that the debugger finished the last run and exited.

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse, try right-clicking on the project giving you problems and clicking on "Clean Project".

Here's an image showing that menu.
[image: Menu with the Clean Project option selected]